# XSLT Reports in Selenium

Tags: selenium, xslt, report

How to create XSLT reports in Selenium project bases on Java and Ant.

I have already added that to my project but the result is not as per my expectation. All Testcases are passing but some are showing failed in reports

Comment: please share your code or any other details which might help others to debug, reproduce or analyse your issue.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT reports can be generated based on the results of your TestNG.XML file. if you are using TestNG as unit testing framework make sure to place -output directory of the TestNG  should be available in home directory.

Read this (http://learn-automation.com/generate-xslt-report-in-selenium/) post you will get better Idea.